# Plotting nested vectors

Tags: clojure, plot, incanter

Consider a function that outputs a nested vector such as

```
[[[-0.6925523827697917 -0.4095089425269985]
  [-0.03856010899727634 0.8427233420960013]
  [-2.609986195686694E-13 -1.680032093051418E-12]]
 [[0.7203362514229046 -0.3494564274369062]]]
```

In between single brackets, i.e. `[-0.6925523827697917 -0.4095089425269985]`, are numbers to be plotted in Cartesian coordinates.

Additionally there are vectors within another bracket, i.e.

`[[0.7203362514229046 -0.3494564274369062]]`

which denotes a cluster.

I am seeking to plot the points, which are the vectors above, and draw a line connecting points within a cluster. So, the points within the cluster `[[-0.6925523827697917 -0.4095089425269985] [-0.03856010899727634 0.8427233420960013] [-2.609986195686694E-13 -1.680032093051418E-12]]` would be connected.

My first thought would be to use Incanter's xy-plot. The part I am unsure is how to go from an indexed structure such as the vector to a point on the plot. Additionally, I am not sure how to draw a line connecting the clustered points. The example above should have one line (preferably smooth) through the three points in the first cluster, and no line through the last cluster since there is just one point within the cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want, but as far as I got you, it's something like this:

```
(use '(incanter core charts interpolation))

(defn my-plot [[data [[cx cy]]]]
  (let [x       (map first data)
        y       (map second data)
        lbound  (apply min x)
        rbound  (apply max x)
        interp  (interpolate data :cubic-hermite)]
    (-> (function-plot interp lbound rbound)
        (add-points x y)
        (add-points [cx] [cy])
        view)))
```

[image: cubic spline interpolation]

I'm using `:cubic-hermite` spline [interpolation](http://liebke.github.io/incanter/interpolation-api.html#incanter.interpolation/interpolate) to make the line smooth, and I'm using [`add-points` function](http://liebke.github.io/incanter/charts-api.html#incanter.charts/add-points) to add data points to the [plot](http://liebke.github.io/incanter/charts-api.html#incanter.charts/function-plot).

You'll find [more interpolation examples here](https://github.com/liebke/incanter/wiki/Interpolation).

But three points isn't enough for good interpolation, so you should consider using linear interpolation instead:

```
(defn my-plot [[data [[cx cy]]]]
  (let [x (map first data)
        y (map second data)]
    (-> (xy-plot x y)
        (add-points x y)
        (add-points [cx] [cy])
        view)))
```

[image: linear interpolation]

## Update:

Let's have a closer look at what I'm doing here.

First, I'm using destructuring to extract data points and cluster coordinates (I'm assuming that you always have a single cluster following your data points):

```
(defn my-plot [[data [[cx cy]]]]
```

Then I'm breaking nested vector of `[x y]` pairs into two vectors (one for each dimension):

```
  (let [x (map first data)
        y (map second data)]
```

Then I'm creating a plot object and drawing a line on it using your data points:

```
    (-> (xy-plot x y)
```

Then I'm adding original data point (blue dots):

```
        (add-points x y)
```

and your cluster (green dot):

```
        (add-points [cx] [cy])
```

Finally, I'm displaying resulting plot:

```
        view)))
```

In my first example I'm also using interpolation to make the line smoother:

```
        lbound  (apply min x)
        rbound  (apply max x)
        interp  (interpolate data :cubic-hermite)]
    (-> (function-plot interp lbound rbound)
```

I'm using `function-plot` here because `interp` object is a function.

Comment: If I wanted to plot without the interpolation what would be required to remove from the first function? I tried removing the line `interp` and interp from `function-plot` but am passing too many args to the function (2).

Comment: See my second example for plot without interpolation.

Comment: Using the latter my-plot, how would I modify it to plot the original points and the clusters in the same graph? @LeonidBeschastny

Comment: Also, I haven't been able to figure out the green dot that appears in all of the graphs. Could you please explain this object.

Comment: Green dot IS your cluster. =)

Comment: Ok, now I see. But I meant to plot all vectors output, i.e. floating points with a single bracket [...]. Then to plot on the same graph all clusters, i.e. vectors within a bracket []. So clusters are the entities with double brackets [[...]] @LeonidBeschanstny

Comment: The following function would find the center of the cluster `(defn arithmeans [& x] (map #(/ % (count x)) (apply map + x)))`

Comment: My goal was to demonstrate the principles of plotting in Incanter, so I assumed that you always have a single cluster following all your data points.